# What is the real long type range in java?

Tags: java, types, primitive-types

According to every reference I've ever found, the long type in Java ranges from -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to +9,223,372,036,854,775,807. 
I've written the following code below,

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    long x = 12 * 24 * 60 * 1000 * 1000; 
    long y = 12 * 60 * 1000 * 1000;
    System.out.print(x / y); 
}
```

The expected result is 24; But the output was 0.

Comment: The entire thing is being evaluated as an `int` and then converted to long.

Comment: You need to define that you want to use long not int explicitly like so `12l`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your literals are int's...

And that gives that x = 100130816 instead of 17280000000

Here you go:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        long x = 12L * 24L * 60L * 1000L * 1000L;
        long y = 12L * 60L * 1000L * 1000L;
        System.out.print(x + " " + y + " " + x / y);

}
```

The result is 24

P.S. i solved this the first time, but you deleted the Question...

Comment: Please use `L` instead of `l` as the long indicator. Both are equally valid, but one of them is way more likely to be mistaken for a `1` in some fonts (yes, I know that good coding fonts don't have that problem as much, but why have the problem at all, when it's so easy to avoid?)

Answer (score 3):

in your code the   `12 * 24 * 60 * 1000 * 1000` is evaluated as an ints. and then you are assigning it to long.

try

```
long x = 12L * 24 * 60 * 1000 * 1000; 
    long y = 12L * 60 * 1000 * 1000;
    System.out.print(x / y); 
}
```

Comment: Aura, your code was wrong because java interprets the value of (12 * 24 * 60 * 1000 * 1000) as an int. And you storing this integer value into variable of type long.

Comment: For example you cant write **short a = 50; a = 50 + a;** because you will try to store int value into short variable.